# Making MS Access queries that allow data entry to PostgreSQL database via an ODBC driver

Tags: postgresql, ms-access-2010

I've been asked to modify an Access database by putting the data themselves into a Postgres database while keeping the old Access file as a frontend. So far everything has worked just fine, with every linked table, query and form working just like before when viewed.

The issue is, however, that all of the forms call on MS Access queries which users can insert data into, but after the tables have been migrated into PostgreSQL, those queries no longer allow for data inserts, which means the forms no longer allow for data inserts. I can edit the rows already entered, but I cannot make new rows, and I can insert new rows into the linked tables. This is as a superuser.

I have made Access queries in the past that allowed for data entry to a Postgres database, but I don't have access to those files now, and I can't for the life of me figure out what I did diferently back then.

Highly appreciate any leads. Couldn't find anything on this. Using MS Access 2010 and PostgreSQL 9.1

---

## Solved

Andre pointed out that these MS Access queries must include the primary key to give the option of creating new rows. Once I added the id field to the query, the forms worked like they did before.

Comment: More details are needed. Can you insert records when you open the linked table in Access? But not the query? What if the query is simply `SELECT * FROM myTable`?

Comment: Dear Andre - I can insert records to the linked tables. Interestingly I can also add records to * queries, like this one: SELECT *
FROM [B0a-Prosjekt]
ORDER BY [B0a-Prosjekt].Prosjekt;  ----------- but not this one: SELECT [B0a-Prosjekt].Prosjekt, [B0a-Prosjekt].[Prosjekt navn]
FROM [B0a-Prosjekt]
ORDER BY [B0a-Prosjekt].Prosjekt;

Comment: Interesting. Do you get an error msg, or does Access simply not offer the empty "new record" row? -- Does this query include the primary key? If not, try adding it to the query columns.

Comment: You're totally right Andre -- the query has to include the primary key, and then Access gives you the option for the empty 'new record row'. Thanks for sharing your knowledge on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, supplied by Andre, is that simple MS Access queries allow for inserts into PostgreSQL if the queries include the primary key of the queried table. Cheers!